# AutoEncoder with one hot encoded vectors as input

Tags: neural-networks, categorical-data, categorical-encoding, autoencoders

I have a simple autoencoder model with one hidden layer and 32 as encoding dimension. The activation function for the encoder is Relu. The activation function for the decoder is the sigmoid function. My input for this model is a one hot encode vector (matrix). I got as output a matrix but not with 0 and 1, because I am expecting a one hot vector as output so I can inverse the one hot Encoding transformation.

So the problem is that my model is working fine (loss = 0.0248 and accuracy= 0.99) but when I inverse the one hot encoding transformation, I get the same label for every decoded row. It doesn't make any sense. I don't know what might be the problem ? I changed the activation functions, the encoding dimensions but still.

Comment: what is the distribution of the data like? is it also heavily imbalanced?

Comment: wel I don't know exactly how is it distributed, but do you recommend a way how to visualize it ?

Comment: I tried to calculate precision according to this link http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_precision_recall.html, I got as average micro precision 0.48. Does this imply that I have an umbalanced dataset ?

Comment: @shimao I managed to plot the distribution of the data also before applying the one hot encoding transformation. Here you will find the data distribution https://imgur.com/8UGX4SG. It is clear that the data is not that balanced. what do you suggest for me ?

Comment: @EmnaJaoua did you found a solution? Could you share your code? I run into the same problem.

Comment: @botenvouwer As I remember the solution that I used is when I applied the one hot encoding, I returned not only the encoded vector but also the encoder that I worked with (label encoder). later I used this label encoder for applying one hot decoding :) I apologize for the late reply.

Comment: @EmnaJaoua Ah so if I'm correct, your problem was with the decoding and not with the generated output. But did you get the expected output from the autoencoder?

Comment: @botenvouwer In fact I didn't get the expected output from the autoencoder. The output was not so similar to the input. I remember that I had about 75% precision. In fact my output was xml file. it was not readable by a browser because the output was not as expected.

Comment: What loss function were you using? I have success with `relu` activation and `categorical_hinge` loss.